# What is the meaning of the symbol "@" Before A String Literal?

Tags: asp.net

What is the concept **@** Before coming to select this code?

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = @"SELECT tblstore.storname,tblproduct.pid, tblproduct.pname, tblproduct.pprice, tblproduct.publisher, tblproduct.writer FROM tblproduct INNER JOIN tblstore ON tblproduct.storeid = tblstore.storeid WHERE tblproduct.pname LIKE @likeText";
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("likeText", "%" + txtName.Text + "%");
```

Comment: Have a [look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

that defines a string literal

[string (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

to quote msdn

"The advantage of verbatim strings is that escape sequences are not processed, which makes it easy to write, for example, a fully qualified file name"